# jQuery: (live) scroll Event handler on dynamically added element? How else should I solve this

Tags: jquery, scroll, live

I got a (dynamically added) element that repositions based on horizontal scrolling, meaning it can go offscreen. Attached to that element, there is another one which may not go offscreen, it has to stay onscreen. So my idea was to use an event handler which asks for the elements position whenever you scroll. If the position-left attribute gets below a certain number, the attached element will then reposition.

You know these kind of elements, it's like a menu/navigation that scrolls with you up to a certain point and then appears to be position-fixed.

I tried this, but it's not working, probably because the elements are added with javascript. I tried `live("scroll"..` aswell, but that didn't work either.

```
$(window).scroll(function(ev) { 
alert($("#scrElem").position().left);
  alert("work");    
  if ($("#scrElem").position().left >= 203) {
      $("#scrElem .attElem").css("left", ($("#scrElem").position().left - 203) + "px");
    };
});
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe this helps:
I'm using the tinyscrollbar plugin, here is a readable version of it ( http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.js ). Basically this plugin is firing events when scrolled. That's what I want, I even saw where he did it:

```
oWrapper[0].addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false );
oWrapper[0].addEventListener( 'mousewheel', wheel, false );
oWrapper[0].addEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', function( event ){
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: can't you set `position: fixed` after scrolling to a certain point?

Comment: Yes I could, but the event is not finding my element because it was created with javascript long after the DOM ready event.

Answer (score -1):

This independently on the objects that you'll append to the container will work, but don't destroy the .main_container

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.main_container', function() {



});
```

Comment: Your example is not working for me, it doesn't give me any feedback (alert and such).

Comment: Its not supposed to... This is just to check how to bind an event to a DOM element and keep it always alive, you can do wherever you want inside the function.

Comment: I altered your example to suit my situation, of course. It still wouldn't work, but I found a different, adequate solution.

Answer (score -1):

WHile looking for a different issue, I luckily found a way to make it work in my case:

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" 
$("#scrElem").live(mousewheelevt, function(e){
 // do my position stuff
});
```

Simple as that, it works!

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this solition:

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
```

is that it doesn't work when I scroll by clicking the scrollbar and dragging it.

What I've realized is that you don't need to attach scroll event as if it's a dynamic element. Just treat it as if it is static:

```
$("#scrElem").on('scroll', function(e){
 // do my position stuff
});
```

and that works perfectly!